# FontAwesome icon incorrect font-size

Tags: css, font-awesome

I'm using the following code to display a 300x300px circle with a chart icon in it:

```
<style>
/* 150px=300px/2 */
.fa-icon-300 { font-size: 150px !important; }
</style>
<span class="fa-stack fa-icon-300">
    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-film fa-inverse fa-stack-1x"></i>
</span>
```

However, even though the span's size is 300x300px, the actual icon is a little bit smaller.

Look at Safari's dev tool:

[image: Screenshot]

I need the icon to be exactly 300x300px large. Any suggestions?

Best Regards

Comment: You are sure that this "icon" really uses all space of the available area? To me this looks like the glyph itself has some internal padding.

Comment: Haven't thought about this, you might be right ... Any ideas how to verify this? Unfortunately I don't have any knowledge about the inner workings of webfonts.

Comment: Webfonts work like every other font too... First idea would be simply to look for other glyphs: take the tallest one you can find and compare it... Maybe there is some blank or full glyph available? Then you could put it over a colored background in a fiddler and compare different glyphs. You will probably see different "paddings".

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the size of the whole image, not only the icon. The icon is padded with 20px from each side.

[image]

So, what we're doing now? Simple math. `300*(300/260) = 346,15...`. Just set the size of the image to 346 and you'll get your icon to be ~300px.

Comment: I understand what you mean, and your suggested solution works. However, I am not really satisfied with it, because the outer div box needs more space, too (346,x px). I would much more like to be able to just remove the padding from the icon, but as it looks like the padding is part of the icon itself, it cannot be removed using CSS (if I understand it correctly).